# PG: How to show total count for this query if result is 0

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 9.6 table called `selected_media`, with a column called `_type` that is set to either `book` or `movie`.

I want to select the `COUNT` of each type, in 1 single row, like this:

`25 | 715`

To do this, I have this query:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'book'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS books_count,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'movie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS movies_count
FROM selected_media
WHERE subscriber_id = $1
```

The problem is 2 fold:

1. I want each column to show the respective **total count for that _type only** if the sum in that column happens to be 0 (none selected). This is because the UI/UX states *"selecting 0 books or movies is the same as selecting all of them"*.
2. It needs to be fast, this table will have millions of rows in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` with `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'book') AS books_count,
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'movie') AS movies_count
FROM selected_media
WHERE subscriber_id = $1;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html).

---

**EDIT**

Use a nested subquery to achieve your first need:

```
SELECT
    CASE books_count WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selected_media WHERE _TYPE = 'book') ELSE books_count END AS books_count_final,
    CASE movies_count WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selected_media WHERE _TYPE = 'movie') ELSE movies_count END AS movies_count_final   
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'book') AS books_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'movie') AS movies_count
    FROM 
        selected_media
    WHERE 
        subscriber_id = $1
    ) AS sub_query
```

Or using a `CTE`:

```
WITH selected_media_sub AS (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'book') AS books_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'movie') AS movies_count
    FROM 
        selected_media
    WHERE 
        subscriber_id = $1
 )

SELECT
    CASE books_count WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selected_media WHERE _TYPE = 'book') ELSE books_count END AS books_count_final,
    CASE movies_count WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selected_media WHERE _TYPE = 'movie') ELSE movies_count END AS movies_count_final   
FROM selected_media_sub;
```

BTW, if you need just a non-zero count you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'book'), 0), 1) AS books_count,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'movie'), 0), 1) AS movies_count
FROM 
    selected_media
WHERE 
    subscriber_id = $1
```

Comment: That is a great refactoring of what I had (thanks!), but it still doesnt do point #1 that I need.

Comment: Oops. I'm little confused on what you need. Let's say the count by type is 0, so you need the overall count?

Comment: Correct. It should filter as you have it if the count is anything > 0, but if its 0 it needs to simply do select `COUNT(*) from selected_media WHERE _type = 'x'` (but also should be fast.. not sure if multiple counts here can be combined, etc)